# ComboBox Validation - Options

Tags: c#, combobox, keyvaluepair

I've been asked to review some code written by someone else and they've used a method to validate their comboxboxes that I've never seen before, and I'm not sure if it's a better way and/or what the point of it is.

For ease, let's say there's one combobox called cmbClient and the code needs to ensure an item has been selected from that combobox.

I would normally use:

```
if(cmbClient.SelectedIndex > 0)
{
   callSomeMethod(cmbClient.SelectedIndex);
}
```

However, what they do is:

```
if(((KeyValuePair<int, string>)cmbClient.SelectedItem).Key > 0)
{
   callSomeMethod((KeyValuePair<int, string>)cmbClient.SelectedItem).Key);
}
```

It SEEMS as though their method is much more confusing and convoluted for no real advantage. And when I compile/run both options, mine seems to run significantly quicker. BUT...is there something I'm missing? Is there a method to their madness that I'm unaware of?